# null return on getParameter text field in jsp page running on tomcat 5.x

Tags: java, javascript, forms, jsp, tomcat5.5

I am getting a weird error of page constantly fluctuating between nullpointerexception to actual execution on every form submit. I am writing a simple jsp page and running it on tomcat 5.x server. I am taking data from text field of a form and processing it upon form submit. Here is the code I am trying:

```
form id="mainForm" method=POST action="index.jsp">

<input type="text" name="reportName" size=20> 



<a class="btnBlue btnBlueRight" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('mainForm').submit();" > 

            <% 
            if(request.getParameter("reportName")!=null){
            //do things
            else
            //print message
            %>
```

for this code, page address in address bar is localhost:8080/# or localhost:8080/index.jsp for every form submit. I am new to jsp so could not resolve this.

Comment: please include the npe (null-pointer exception).

Comment: i handled the exception so it just shows java.lang.nullpointerexception

Comment: **request.getParameter("reportName")** happens on page build, it could be for the submit/query that is building the page the parameter was not sent. If the jsp was invoked directly, for example, there would be no parameters unless specified in the url.

Comment: i get the point that input text is the issue and somehow it is not getting initialized for first form submit, but it works perfectly well if i resubmit the form!

Comment: there is no npe in the code shown.  The exception will have a line number where the npe occurs.  if you have code in the `//do things` or `print message` section you might include that and someone can find your NPE for you.

Comment: @pbd - that would be my expected behaviour.

Comment: the //print message is message i set up for NPE. So the output is either the //print message (1st form submit) or //do things (on  resubmit)

Comment: @BevynQ- how can i make sure i set these parameters for execution by jsp?

Comment: It's because the reportName does not set any where for the first time page load!

Comment: @YasserZamani- I did not understand, you mean set it within jsp code?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the reportName does not set any where **for the first time** page load! e.g. try to navigate

> localhost:8080/index.jsp?reportName=all